# C# Regex to validate phone number

Tags: c#, regex

It would be great if someone could help me with a Regex for phone numbers. Following are the conditions:

- If + is present, then it should be the first character
- Allowed characters are numbers (  ) space - and .
- Minimum of 6 numbers and max 12
- ( , ) and space can come anywhere in the string
- - shouldn't be the first and last character and shouldn't appear immediately after +, if + is present.

Here are some valid numbers:

- +93483227359
- +1 703 335 65123
- 34565464
- 001 (703) 332-6261
- +1703.338.6512
- +934-83227359
- (111)123-4567
- 111-123-4567

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to check, are you sure you want "+)-)-)333(((,111" to be a valid phone number?

Comment: @JonSkeet well, I'm pretty sure `tel:+)-)-)333(((,111` is a valid tel URI, so one could argue that if it's good enough for RFC 3966 then... :) I'd be more worried that the min and max number of digits is Internationally valid.

Comment: Indeed, my own is 12digits after the +, so if given in the form local to a given country it would be at least 13digits long.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try with:

```
^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$
```

However it does not handle number counting

Comment: @PabitraDash That's what I wrote.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but for those who need to work with phone numbers, there is a .NET port of Google's [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/): [libphonenumber-csharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/).